# Website form data stop saving into Google spreadsheet from yesterday i.e 26/05/2015

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created an application where my website form data will be stored into a google spreadsheet. It was working fine till yesterday i.e 26/05/2015. But from today i.e 27/05/2015 it suddenly stopped working. And no value is adding into the google spreadsheet.

I have used the below mentioned class for spreadsheet application

spreadsheet.php:

```
<?php

    class spreadsheet {
        private $token;
        private $spreadsheet;
        private $worksheet;
        private $spreadsheetid;
        private $worksheetid;

        public function __construct() {
        }

        public function authenticate($username, $password) {
            $url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
            $fields = array(
                "accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
                "Email" => $username,
                "Passwd" => $password,
                "service" => "wise",
                "source" => "pfbc"
            );
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($curl);

            if($status == 200) {
                if(stripos($response, "auth=") !== false) {
                    preg_match("/auth=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $response, $matches);
                    $this->token = $matches[1];
                }
            }
        }

        public function setSpreadsheet($title) {
            $this->spreadsheet = $title;
        }

        public function setWorksheet($title) {
            $this->worksheet = $title;
        }

        public function add($data) {
            if(!empty($this->token)) {
                $url = $this->getPostUrl();
                if(!empty($url)) {
                    $headers = array(
                        "Content-Type: application/atom+xml",
                        "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->token,
                        "GData-Version: 3.0"
                    );

                    $columnIDs = $this->getColumnIDs();
                    if($columnIDs) {
                        $fields = '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">';
                        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                            $key = $this->formatColumnID($key);
                            if(in_array($key, $columnIDs))
                                $fields .= "<gsx:$key><![CDATA[$value]]></gsx:$key>";
                        }
                        $fields .= '</entry>';

                        $curl = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
                        $response = curl_exec($curl);
                        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                        curl_close($curl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function getColumnIDs() {
            $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" . $this->spreadsheetid . "/" . $this->worksheetid . "/private/full?max-row=1";
            $headers = array(
                "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->token,
                "GData-Version: 3.0"
            );
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($curl);

            if($status == 200) {
                $columnIDs = array();
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                if($xml->entry) {
                    $columnSize = sizeof($xml->entry);
                    for($c = 0; $c < $columnSize; ++$c)
                        $columnIDs[] = $this->formatColumnID($xml->entry[$c]->content);
                }       
                return $columnIDs;      
            }

            return "";
        }

        private function getPostUrl() {
            $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?title=" . urlencode($this->spreadsheet);
            $headers = array(
                "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->token,
                "GData-Version: 3.0"
            );
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

            if($status == 200) {
                $spreadsheetXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                if($spreadsheetXml->entry) {
                    $this->spreadsheetid = basename(trim($spreadsheetXml->entry[0]->id));
                    $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" . $this->spreadsheetid . "/private/full";
                    if(!empty($this->worksheet))
                        $url .= "?title=" . $this->worksheet;

                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    $response = curl_exec($curl);
                    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    if($status == 200) {
                        $worksheetXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                        if($worksheetXml->entry)
                            $this->worksheetid = basename(trim($worksheetXml->entry[0]->id));
                    }
                }
            }
            curl_close($curl);
            if(!empty($this->spreadsheetid) && !empty($this->worksheetid))
                return "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" . $this->spreadsheetid . "/" . $this->worksheetid . "/private/full";

            return "";
        }

        private function formatColumnID($val) {
            return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/", "", strtolower($val));
        }
    }

?>
```

and use it in following way:

include 'spreadsheet.php';

```
$doc = new spreadsheet();
$doc->authenticate("example@example.com", "example");
$doc->setSpreadsheet("Tester");
$doc->setWorksheet("Sheet1");
$my_data = array("First Name" => "John", "Last Name" => "Doe");
$doc->add($my_data);
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No Error. The most unfortunate thing is that it stopped working suddenly from 26th of May. before that the same code was working fine. Can you please hel me in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

The ClientLogin method, which has been deprecated for a number of years, has now been turned off. It will return a 404 when trying to authenticate. You will need to migrate to OAuth for authentication.

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps

Here is an updated PHP library that uses OAuth - https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client. The author also has a sample project with instructions to generate OAuth access tokens.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But can you please assist me the way I can migrate from my existing system to OAuth for authentication? any source code or  tutorial about this would be really appreciable. I have already search in google to findout a solution or sample code but unable to do so.

Comment: I'm also looking for a similar solution. Every article I've found uses the old GoogleLogin method that is now useless. Would love to get the "Spreadsheet" class as listed in the original question working again via OAuth.

Comment: Check out the spreadsheet library in my edited answer. I set it up yesterday and it is working the same as the previous library but now with OAuth

Comment: In your edited answer I have downloaded the example but didn't got any specific class or file by which I can get the job done. Can you please provide us any specific example using which we can sort out the problem?

Comment: The author of the library has this project [php-google-oauth](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-oauth) which details how to generate OAuth access tokens. Using both projects you should be able to replicate your previous setup but now using OAuth instead of ClientLogin.